# Can't Sign Into Instagram - Phone Number Request

Tags: instagram

Last Week i joined Instagram. Yesterday it started asking for a Phone Number as a Security Check.

I gave them my old Phone Number for my old Phone which i hardley use. They text you a code so you sign in once you have this without the Number Check. I have not been sent the code.

I have been using Software called Blue Stacks on my PC when i wanted to Upload a Picture to Instagram.
.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueStacks

My Phone is old so i have to Upload from my PC. I am running Windows Ten Pro 64.

Is there anyway i get get round this? I could not find a Email contact for Instagram. I have tried the Retry thingbut still no Joy.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to cross verify your address is simply go to settings tab > private information under which you see the email you can edit or change it, you will then recieve a confirmation email. Additionally make sure of the [bluestacks virus](https://www.onlineprivacytips.co/security/is-bluestacks-safe-to-use/#2) at times it tear down your system performance.